# How to add a clickable button to a DropdownMenuItem as a child in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add a `DateTimePicker` to a `dropdown menu` so the user can select a particular `date` through it. How to Display a `DateTimePicker` after a `dropDropdownMenuItem` is `clicked`? I've included the code below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class CustomDropDown extends StatefulWidget {
  DateTime selectedEndDate = new DateTime.now();

  @override
  _CustomDropDownState createState() => _CustomDropDownState();
}

class _CustomDropDownState extends State<CustomDropDown> {
  var _value = '1';

  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();

  Future<Null> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(2015, 8),
        lastDate: DateTime(2101));
    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate)
      setState(() {
        selectedDate = picked;
        widget.selectedEndDate = picked;
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: DropdownButton(
      items: [
        DropdownMenuItem(
          value: "1",
          child: InkWell(
            child: Text(
              'Forever',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.teal, fontSize: 23),
            ),
            onTap: () => (widget.selectedEndDate = DateTime(2100)),
          ),
        ),
        DropdownMenuItem(
          value: "2",
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () => _selectDate(context),
            child: Text(
              'Select end date: ${selectedDate.day}/${selectedDate.month}/${selectedDate.year}',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.teal, fontSize: 23),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
      onChanged: (val) => setState(() {
        _value = val;
      }),
      value: _value,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.teal, fontSize: 23),
      isExpanded: true,
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the value you select in onChange():

```
onChanged: (val) => 
   setState(() {
   if (val == "2") {
     //Display select date
   }
   _value = val;
})
```

Comment: the problem is the inkwell and the DropdownMenuItem are seperate entities, so after clicking the inkwell, the DateTimePicker is displayed and the control goes back to InkWell instead of the DropdownMenuItem. Plus you need to click on the inkwell area only to inwoke the  DateTimePicker, otherwise it doesnt.

Comment: So you want to display DateTimePicker when you click to Inkwell in DropDownMenuItem but not changing your value in your DropDownMenu? I think it can't because onChange will be activated everytime since InkWell was inside of DropDownMenuItem. As long as you click on Item

Comment: No, i want to bypass inkwell altogether and invoke DateTimePicker on DropDownMenuItem click. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: If you show me your design it gonna be easier. You want to display DateTimePicker in your DropDownMenuItem? This is how i understand your design: when you click on your DropDownMenuItem, it will not be collapsed and display DateTimePicker inside that Item then you can choose date. right?

Comment: Ok , im sorry for not being able to explain it properly, so what i want is a DropDownButton where if the user selects a DropDownMenuItem, a DateTimePicker should be displayed on screen, then after the user selects a date and presses ok, that date should be displayed as text in the DropDownMenuItem.